# Inactivate Input Text by Selecting Radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I select laptop radio button, the input text for computer should be not be enable to add any data and the the background should be grey instead of white.

Same logic if you select computer radio button and this time it would laptop.

I do not know how to create it.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<form>


    <div class="radio-group">

        <input id="laptop" type="radio" name="device" value="laptop" checked>
        <span class="radio-choice-name">
            <label for="laptop">laptop</label>
            <input type="text" value="" />
        </span>

        </BR>


        <input id="computer" type="radio" name="device" value="computer">
        <span class="radio-choice-name">
            <label for="computer">computer</label>
            <input type="text" value=""" />
        </span>         

    </div>


</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your jscode please

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: I don't know where to start. I tried but failed.

Comment: I don't have any jscode.

Comment: @HelloWorld give id's to the input's and then on selected radio buton disable the other input id for computer and enable the input for the laptop

Comment: to do this you should write the java script !

Comment: Do you have any other JS or jQuery at all on your site/page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give id's to the input's and then on selected radio buton disable the other input id for computer and enable the input for the laptop

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=radio][name=sex]').click(function(){
        var related_class=$(this).val();
        $('.'+related_class).prop('disabled',false);

        $('input[type=radio][name=sex]').not(':checked').each(function(){
            var other_class=$(this).val();
            $('.'+other_class).prop('disabled',true);
        });
    });
});
```

[**Simmilar Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8NynQ/)

Comment: can you elaborate  bit please

Comment: I would like to make some complementory of the code. Same input text as disabled, I also would like to change the background color into yellow. I tried to add the code "$('.'+other_class).prop('style', 'background-color : yellow;' );" but It didn't go so well. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: It is important in this context to use "style" because I'm using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following in `jQuery`. Let me know if you needed a pure javascript solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".radio-group").on("change", ":radio", function() {     
        $(":text").prop("disabled", true);
        $(this).next(".radio-choice-name").find(":text").prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

```css
input[disabled] { background-color: #eee }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    
    
    <div class="radio-group">
        
        <input id="laptop" type="radio" name="sex" value="laptop" checked />
            <span class="radio-choice-name">
                <label for="laptop">laptop</label>
                <input type="text" value="" />
            </span>
            
            <br/>
        
        
            <input id="computer" type="radio" name="sex" value="computer" />
            <span class="radio-choice-name">
                <label for="computer">computer</label>
                <input type="text" value="" disabled />
            </span>         

    </div>


</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below using jQuery:

**HTML**

```
<form>


<div class="radio-group">

    <input id="laptop" type="radio" name="sex" value="laptop" checked>
    <span class="radio-choice-name">
        <label for="laptop">laptop</label>
        <input id="laptopVal" type="text" value="" />
    </span>

    </BR>


    <input id="computer" type="radio" name="sex" value="computer">
    <span class="radio-choice-name">
        <label for="computer">computer</label>
        <input id="computerVal"type="text" value=""" />
    </span>         

</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    function handleClick(el) {
        $('input[type=text]').css('background-color', 'grey');
        $('input[type=text]').attr('readonly', 'true');
        $('#' + el.attr('id') + 'Val').css('background-color', 'white');
        $('#' + el.attr('id') + 'Val').attr('readonly', 'false');
    }
    handleClick($('#laptop'));

    $("input:radio").click(function() {
      handleClick($(this));
    });
   });
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/de2pak08/64ua21g1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have done slight change to your html below, just added "class" attribute to input text and assigned value same as radio button values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <body>
     <form>
       <div class="radio-group">
        <input id="laptop" type="radio" name="device" value="laptop" checked>
         <span class="radio-choice-name">
          <label for="laptop">laptop</label>
          <input class="laptop" type="text" value="" />
         </span>
       <br>
       <input id="computer" type="radio" name="device" value="computer">
       <span class="radio-choice-name">
        <label for="computer">computer</label>
        <input class="computer" type="text" value="" disabled/>
       </span>         
     </div>
   </form> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
    $('input:radio').on('change', function(){
               var value = $(this).val();
               $('.radio-group').find('input[type=text]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
               $('.' + value).removeAttr('disabled');

       }
    );
});
</script>
```

I think you will find this very easy approach.